# what kind of cable connector do I use on an outdoor junction box?

Tags: electrical

I'm planning on installing an outdoor light in a place that does not currently have one using an outdoor box like [this](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/dda158d5-f147-4bca-b53b-43344a1a13b0/svn/gray-bell-boxes-brackets-5372-0-64_1000.jpg).  The "knockout" is threaded, I think it is 1/2".  What kind of cable connector do I use with this?  It is ok to make a hole in the wall (wood and metal flashing) and run Romex from the inside of the house into this box?

Comment: Yes, it is threaded 1/2" *trade size* and will play nicely with most plumbing pipe, all threaded conduit obviously and most box fittings which are also 1/2" trade sizs.

Comment: Are you suggesting the NM cable (Romex) will run *outside* exposed? Can you upload some pictures of the area or provide a drawing of some sort? Also, why not use an old work ceiling junction box?

Comment: Why are you using a box that lacks KOs in the back for this?

Comment: I have used boxes like that all the ports are sealed and you punch the ones you want to use out.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I suspect that box *does* have a bottom knockout but the knockout disc is fully sealed until knocked out, to retain watertightne---nope, could not keep a straight face...

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong picture.  The box I will use does in fact have a knockout in the back.  I updated the link to reflect this.  @HariGanti The NM will run through the wall and then through some flashing directly into the box.  It will not be outside at any point.  The surface mount box is easier to mount than trying to cut through the flashing and whatever wood is inside the wall to get a box in there.

Comment: As I alluded in my last comment, "weathertightness" doesn't work and the box is outside.  I would ask your AHJ whether they're ok with Romex being outside for 9 inches.

Comment: My installation will be very similar to this one https://ask-the-electrician.com/outdoor-motion-fixtures.html.  He doesn't seem to use any clamp or connector into the box.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this video from homedepot.com](http://videos.homedepot.com/detail/videos/lighting/video/1032722924001/how-to-install-floodlights-for-security:-part-2) and [this page from thisoldhouse.com](https://www.thisoldhouse.com/how-to/how-to-install-garage-floodlight) I can use a standard metallic threaded cable connector like this [one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-8-in-Non-Metallic-NM-Twin-Screw-Cable-Clamp-Connectors-5-Pack-20511/100133208)  The thisoldhouse.com page also mentions using Romex from the inside through the wall to the box outside.